# iOS - Get Keyboard size before UiTextField Begins Editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard, uitextfielddelegate

i need to get keyboard size before delegate

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
return TRUE;}
```

i am using notification **UIKeyboardDidShowNotification** to get keyboard size but **textFieldShouldBeginEditing** is called before **UIKeyboardDidShowNotification**.

How can i achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call "UIKeyboardWillShowNotification" instead of "UIKeyboardDidShowNotification"

Hope this helps!